# Add custom css to Helix3 and SP PageBuilder

Tags: css, joomla, stylesheet, joomla-extensions

I've installed Helix3 Template and SP Page Builder (free edition)

The fonts tab missing on the Helix3 Template. The template however Typography tab where basic things like Font Family, Font Weight, etc can be configured for the template.

Can CSS be created within Joomla/Helix interface or it has to be created outside (using a CSS editor like Notepad++)

How do I add custom css and refer to it for any given Page and override default.

How to add multiple css files to a single page

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom CSS rules inside the template configuration: go to Custom code tab and then Custom CSS.

You can create a new file called custom.css in the template's css folder too.

If you want to create custom CSS for a concrete page you can write them using the menu item class inserted by the template in the body tag. For example:

.item-135 .h1 {color: red;}

With this CSS rule you obtain red level 1 headers only for the menu item 135.

Best regards